# What do numbers mean in magento patches?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, patches, security

During installation of the latest Magento security patch the interesting question appeared in my head what do numbers mean in name of patches? like 9767 or the latest one 10266?

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the JIRA system Magento uses internally. The patch number is the number of the ticket in the JIRA system AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with the JIRA system used for Magento internally. It stands for EE Support so in JIRA I assume you will see SUPEE-404 etc.

See https://twitter.com/piotrekkaminski/status/414091975034277888

Comment: Thanks, that's Intreresting, but there is no SUPCE patches :)

Comment: @Nick because there's no support for CE right  ;) support is only for people who paid for EE ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism right, but patches are available for CE version as well

Comment: Please flag questions as duplicate if they are already answered on the site, instead of copying the answer from the original question.